# Deserialize json object list with newton in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a json string that i am trying to deserialize into an object list using Newton. But it gives the

> error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

The format of the json string is.

```
 [ { "key": "1", "value": "Package1" }, { "key": "some name", "value": "Package2" } ]
```

the Model is defined as

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

And i'm using the following method to deserialize it, where json is the string listed above.

```
var resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is the json text that you're passing to the Deserialize method ? Because it should work completely fine for me. Can you output `json` object to the Console and paste it here ?

Comment: Did you escape the quotes?  `var jsonData = "[ { \"key\": \"1\", \"value\": \"Package1\" }, { \"key\": \"some name\", \"value\": \"Package2\" } ]";`

Comment: what you have seems to work fine in fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CvKGau

Comment: Thanks Every for your help, Petre Turuc that was the issue. Once i escaped the quotes it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try giving IDictionary instead of List.